# NSArray becomes NSCFArray when passed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have a method that receives many different kinds of objects and decides what to do with them:

```
-(void)performAction:(NSObject *)myAction withItem:(Item *)myItem {

actionCount = -1;
NSLog(@"-- NEW ACTION ARRAY --");
if ([myAction isMemberOfClass:[Look class]]) {
    currentActionArray = [self createLookArray:(Look *)myAction item:myItem];
} else if ([myAction isMemberOfClass:[Use class]]) {
    currentActionArray = [self createUseArray:(Use *)myAction item:myItem];
} else if ([myAction isMemberOfClass:[Exit class]]) {
    currentActionArray = [self createExitArray:(Exit *)myAction item:myItem];
} else if ([myAction isMemberOfClass:[NSArray class]] ) {
    NSLog(@"--- CUSTOM ACTION --- %@", myAction);
    currentActionArray = (NSArray *)myAction;
} 
[self performNextAction];
```

}

One of four things is going to come through here: Look, Use, Exit or NSArray. The first three  are sent off to become NSArrays, the last is already an NSArray.

Now, when I do pass an NSArray in here from elsewhere, like this:

```
    NSArray *myAction = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myAction1, myAction2, nil];
[controller performAction:myAction withItem:nil];
```

...the custom action is never called, because it reads myAction as an NSCFArray rather than an NSArray. When I try [myAction isMemberOfClass:[NSCFArray class]] it doesn't recognise the CF. The simple way to get it working at the moment is just to assume that anything not a Look, Use or Exit is an NSArray (get rid of the last else if, and just leave it as an else), but that seems sloppy to me.

Anyone know how I can deal with this?

Thanks,
-k.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using `isKindOfClass:` instead of `isMemberOfClass:`.

The first one will return YES for objects that are either instances of the class you send, or subclasses of it, as it may be the case for `NSCFArray`.

Comment: That did it. Forgot about that one. Thanks all.

Comment: I think it is important to note that `NSArray`, `NSString` and many other classes are _class clusters_. Meaning that you never get an object of the specified class, but always a private subclass. Instead of a `NSArray` you will always get a `NSCFArray`, which is a subclass of `NSArray` that is also a till-free bridge to the `CFArrayRef` type from Core Foundation _(A low level framework underneath Cocoa that is not Objective-C)_.

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities worth considering:

- `NSArray` is a class cluster. I don't know the exact behaviour of `-isMemberOfClass:` and `-isKindOfClass:` on clusters. you can check this question for more precisions: [Is it safe to use isKindOfClass: against an NSString instance to determine type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096772/is-it-safe-to-use-iskindofclass-against-an-nsstring-instance-to-determine-type)
- Have you tried `-isKindOfClass:` instead of `-isMemberOfClass:`?

Answer (score 2):

NSСFArray is subclass of NSMutable Array

You can use isKindOfClass to check it

```
if ([myAction isMemberOfClass:[Look class]]) {
    currentActionArray = [self createLookArray:(Look *)myAction item:myItem];
} else if ([myAction isMemberOfClass:[Use class]]) {
        currentActionArray = [self createUseArray:(Use *)myAction item:myItem];
} else if ([myAction isMemberOfClass:[Exit class]]) {
        currentActionArray = [self createExitArray:(Exit *)myAction item:myItem];
} else if ([myAction isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] ) {
        NSLog(@"--- CUSTOM ACTION --- %@", myAction);
        currentActionArray = (NSArray *)myAction;
}
```