# Why does NSDictionary report an unusual class name?

Tags: objective-c, reflection

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([dict class]));
```

This code prints "__NSDictionary0".

For my own classes it prints the actual class name.

Why is NSDictionary identified as __NSDictionary0, and is it safe to depend on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NSDictionary is a class cluster. Read about them here:

[Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html)

As the "actual" class itself is private, no, it is *not* safe to depend on this.

If you need to know if your class is really an NSDictionary or not, use `[dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]];`

Comment: Good answer. And if the next question is "I'm trying to determine if a dictionary is mutable or not", then ... no ... you can't do that either.

Comment: Could you not use `isMemberOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]` for that?

Comment: Yep, isMemberOfClass: can be used to determine if a dictionary is mutable or not.

Comment: This answer has bumped me to exactly 1337 reputation. SWEET.

Comment: With the edit, this answer is now wrong.  So are the suggestions that you can use `-isMemberOfClass:` to check for mutability.  You can't.

Comment: Furthermore, you *shouldn't* need to check for mutability. If you want a mutable version, make a `mutableCopy`.

Comment: Why can't you use isMemberOfClass to find out if your object is a dictionary or not??

Comment: OOPS... I meant isKindOfClass:... updating now.

Comment: I understand why it won't work to check if it's mutable... I also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096772/is-it-safe-to-use-iskindofclass-against-an-nsstring-instance-to-determine-type. But won't it work to check if the object is a dictionary?

Comment: Gendolkari: Yes, you can test whether an object is a kind of NSDictionary to test whether it is a dictionary. Don't test whether it's a kind of NSMutableDictionary or any of the private subclasses.

Comment: (added a space so I can re-instate the up vote that it deserves now that it has been edited :)

Answer (score 20):

`NSDictionary` is a class cluster, as Gendolkari said and [Class Clusters are documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html).

And, no, you can't depend on the exact identity of the private subclass.

You should certainly be able to do the following to determine if it is a dictionary or not:

```
[myThingaMaHoover isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]];
```

Or, at the least, that it is a dictionary as implemented as a part of the `NSDictinoary` class cluster.

What you can't do is use `isKindOfClass:` or `isMemberOfClass:` to determine whether or not a dictionary (or string, array, or set) is mutable.  Consider:

```
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [[NSObject new] autorelease] forKey: @"Bob"];
NSMutableDictionary *m = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [[NSObject new] autorelease] forKey: @"Bob"];
NSLog(@"d class: %@ %@ %@", [d class], [d superclass], [[d superclass] superclass]);
NSLog(@"m class: %@ %@ %@", [m class], [m superclass], [[m superclass] superclass]);
```

This outputs:

```
d class: NSCFDictionary NSMutableDictionary NSDictionary
m class: NSCFDictionary NSMutableDictionary NSDictionary
```

`d` and `m` are both instances of `NSCFDictionary` which inherits from `NSMutableDictionary` (which inherits from `NSDictionary`).

Answer (score 1):

So, basically, you need to know if you are having an NSMutableDictionary or a bare NSDictionary beforehand. Or don't need to know. Or create an NSMutableDictionary from your object (NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary)?

What was the question originally for?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for mutability, your best bet would probably be conformsToProtocol: @protocol(NSMutableCopying)

Comment: NSDictionary and NSArray confirms to NSMutableCopying.

Answer (score 0):

For an NSDictionary mutability test, could't you just to a 'respondsToSelector' for a method that only an NSMutableDictionary would have, like addObject:ForKey:?