# Live streaming audio from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, live-streaming

I would like to stream audio from my iPhone to a remote server but I don't really know what is my best bet.
I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062266/uploading-live-streaming-video-from-iphone) a code for sending small chunks but I have some some audio gaps between chunks.

So I think about FFmpeg or as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242513/how-to-get-real-time-video-stream-from-iphone-camera-and-send-it-to-server) writing my own AAC parser.

Any code sample or advices would be appreciated because I have hard time to get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another core audio based Audio Player: https://github.com/douban/DOUAudioStreamer .

Just see the examples to use.

In my opinion, this one is better designed than Matt Gallagher's one.

Comment: I am getting crash, with buffer is not full. Is it working for you? @fourj

Comment: I finally wrote my own streamer, it's quite simple if you need to stream audio only

Comment: @HaneTV is the code on github by chance? any tips for writing the streamer?

Comment: @Crashalot for sure, I have posted my 1st working implementation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859663/i-converted-caf-to-aac-format-using-tpaacaudioconverter-but-converted-file-durat/17860596#17860596). Bytes contained in the buffer are conform to the [AAC ADTS format](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=ADTS) and are easy to handle on the server side. Only thing to add is the (UDP?) socket for sending each time the function is fired. If you need only AAC packets (for like rtp packetization) you can handle them with inBuffer->mAudioData in HandleInputBuffer() function.

Comment: I'm curious why this is the accepted answer; the provided link seems to be to a streaming audio *player* not a streaming audio *recorder*.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use my Audjustable AudioPlayer player here: https://github.com/tumtumtum/audjustable

Comment: Yeah, the one which is so buggy on iOS 7 you'd better use your own implementation.

Comment: It's used in shipping products running on iOS7. Care to expand on this claim?

Comment: Sure! It's used in ours too. However we have faced with problems such as - not playing audio files shorter than 3 seconds, the player delegate not informing correctly about the end of the playback, which results in the UISlider that reaches its end before the actual playback and finally, we have faced with occasionally playing audio files at the random speed, sometimes twice as fast as the original.

Comment: The reason I made it open source is to share work with others and have them contribute back bug fixes and features. The problems you report don't affect me in the project I'm working on. If you use my work in your own project and find problems related to your use cases then fix them and contribute back. I'm completely amazed that you would make such negative comments to a free open source project which you proudly admit you yourself exploit for free. Absolutely shameless.

Comment: @tumtumtum i am receiving data from udp packets .. the data is encoded in pcm_16bit mono ..any chance i can integrate your library i.e. streamingkit for audio streaming .?

Answer (score 1):

Some good audio stream player on gitHub:-

mattgallagher/AudioStreamer:-https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer
tumtumtum/StreamingKit:-https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit

you can also sreach  on github :-

1)muhku/FreeStreamer

2)nicklockwood/SoundManager

3)AFSoundManager

4)GVMusicPlayerController

Answer (score 0):

for live audio streaming StreamingAudioPlayer is best which is developed by Matt Gallagher and it is easy to use

see this [AudioStreame](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer)