# Sending audio in real time from iphone to server?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, audio, jailbreak

Is it possible to send audio from iphone to server in real time? I am using AQRecorder which records the data and saves it on a file.I was wondering if there was a way of sending the recorded audio to server in real time.I want to send the audio while it is being recorded.Is it possible? Can we redirect the recorded stream to the server instead of a file?

NOTE:I am using the speak here code from apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/speakhere/Listings/Classes_AQRecorder_mm.html

Comment: it's definitely posssible, since this is what apps like Skype do

Comment: Don't know.  I haven't done it.  I was just answering the first part of your question ... that it clearly is doable.

Comment: @Nate I think apps like skype and facebook have more privileges then those given to regular apps.I might be wrong.I am just looking for a way to use the code given in the link and redirect its output to the server

Answer (score 0):

Nate is right. A lot of legitimate apps do that. So, you don't even need to have a jailbroken device.

Take a look at this question: [Live streaming audio from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398010/live-streaming-audio-from-iphone)

You may be interested to look into open source SIP clients for iOS:

- https://code.google.com/p/siphon/
- http://www.pjsip.org
- http://www.linphone.org/eng/linphone/news/linphone-for-iphone.html