# Send iPhone Audio to RTSP server iOS

Tags: iphone, swift, rtsp

I want to send microphone audio input from iPhone device to RTSP server using IP Address and port. Please let me know the process. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Live streaming audio from iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398010/live-streaming-audio-from-iphone)

Comment: The above link provided by you only stream audio from server but i want to send audio to rtsp server. By the way thanks @MwcsMac

Comment: @VedRauniyar - Did you found any solution ?