# How to stream live from iphone camera to server using rtsp?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, real-time, rtsp, rtmp

I am using **AVCaptureSession** to record a video and audio of user. I am getting real time video and audio streams independently. I am able to encode them using **h264 encoder** and **aac encoder** respectively. Now I am not getting how to multiplexing them both and make a stream ? How to send them to specific server url which is protected by userName and Password ? If it can be done using RTMP also then also it's fine.

I have taken a reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242513/how-to-get-real-time-video-stream-from-iphone-camera-and-send-it-to-server)! But I am not getting much out from this.

Is there any RTSP library project which can help me ?

I have been struggling in it from a long.

Is there any solution to my problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use `ffmpeg codec` to compress(encode) your video and stream it to your `RTMP server`.

Comment: Server configuration in my scenario is `**rtsp**`. So I have to use it. @DipenPanchasara

Comment: both are streaming protocols, both provides same mechanism for media streaming. you can use any of them. you need to connect to stream after connecting start sending data over server. its done by available RTMP framework or RTSP frameworks for ios

Comment: @DipenPanchasara : Could you please share some code snippet or tutorial for this.

Comment: @[http://stackoverflow.com/users/394020/jgh]: I am using video core library for publishing my live media on wowza server. In this ramp stream, how can I send username and password in url ?

Comment: Please check it https://github.com/EasyDarwin/EasyPusher