# Objective-C: If an object belongs to a class, does this mean the object isn't nil or null as well?

Tags: objective-c, null

The code below is what I had before in my app.

Before:

```
  if ([dic objectForKey:@"text"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [dic objectForKey:@"text"] != nil && [dic objectForKey:@"text"] != [NSNull Null]) {
       NSString *text = [dic objectForKey:@"text"];
    }
```

I've changed the code to the following below.

After:

```
    if ([dic objectForKey:@"text"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSString *text = [dic objectForKey:@"text"];
    }
```

I believe the results should be the same ,but the latter is neater. Just to be safe, I am asking this question to make sure I'm right about this and not overlooking anything.

Comment: I would write it like this: `id obj = dic[@"text"]; if ([objc isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]) {etc}`.  But be aware when testing against class clusters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096772/is-it-safe-to-use-iskindofclass-against-an-nsstring-instance-to-determine-type

Comment: That class cluster warning is interesting side note, but it is really not applicable here. Besides, the two top answers to that question have seriously misunderstood Apple's point. Apple is merely advising that if you have some interface that prescribes that an object will be of one type, that you should abide by that contract and you shouldn't then test to see if, behind the scenes, it is really another of the cluster's types and try to take advantage of that. In this case, there is no such contract.

Comment: By the way, you can use `dic[@"text"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your simpler code will work.

If `[dic objectForKey:@"text"]` is `nil`, then the call to `isKindOfClass` isn't even called and effectively a result of `false` is returned.

If `[dic objectForKey:@"text"]` is not `nil`, then it must be an `NSString` to be `true` so there's no need to check to see if it is `NSNull`.

In other words, if `[[dic objectForKey:@"text"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]` is `true`, then you already know that it wasn't `nil` and you already know that it isn't `NSNull`, so those checks are not needed.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this for me. I thought the same thing.